# Running Javascript inside ASP.NET code instantly.

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I hope you can help me with my problem. I am executing a SQL query inside ASP.NET code and I am using bing's javascript API. Problem is that I need to do a javascript function before running a query. This function provides geocoordinates based on the address in a string format. I already know for **RegisterStartupScript** and **RegisterClientScriptBlock**, but these two don't work for me because javascript is not executing for some reason. Here is the code. And, I almost forgot, the script is declared properly at the head of the page. Is there any other way to run javascript in C# ASP.Net?

```
    public void calculateCoordinates()
    {
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        Type cstype = this.GetType();
        String csName = "Calculate";
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csName))
        {
            String jsFunction = "calculateGeoCoordinates();";
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csName, jsFunction, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is client side, the code you have is server side, so in short, no, you can't run JavaScript inside of ASP.NET server side code.

However, what you can do is run some ASP.NET, output necessary stuff to your page, including a register script block that fires off the JavaScript you need, which then makes an AJAX or otherwise async call back to your page to fire off your necessary query.